# Looking for older anthology of weird/dark/creepy short stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I remember a few short stories from an anthology, checked out from a library in the early 90's but probably much older, with stories about

1. A stranger who saves a small child from drowning in a stream, only to reveal at the end that he was an angel, saving a young Adolf Hitler.
2. A small child who discovers a "friend" in a secluded area, and when confronting him with a cross made of popsicle sticks, he begins to melt.
3. A young child who discovers a piece of unicorn horn, which grants him wishes for 24 hours only.

Memory is murky, so no telling how accurate these descriptions are, but it's driving me crazy that I can't find them.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

The angel short story is probably "[Angelica](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49879)" by the well-known children's author Jane Yolen.

> The story, set in Linz, Austria, 1898, begins with a young boy named Addie, unable to sleep so he takes a walk and slips down a hill and into a river. He is pulled to safety by an Angel-like figure named Angelica, although she explains that is not her real name. She says he can not pronounce her real name: Pistias Sophia, or the angel of wisdom and faith. They converse and then she leads him back to his house- the Hitler home...

I haven't found matching entries for the other two, but "The Wonderful Day" by Robert Day does have a child making wishes on a unicorn horn. Neither share the same anthology on ISFDB, but they were in *[Young Monsters](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?179117)* and *[Young Witches & Warlocks](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?179089)* respectively, both Isaac Asimov anthologies. As noted by Daphne B. below, *Young Witches & Warlocks* also contains a story named "Stevie and the Dark" by Zenna Henderson which matches with your second story, including a line describing the popsicle stick cross:

> He looked down at it--his precious pocket piece--two pieces of popsicle stick tied together so they looked a little bit like an airplane, and on the top, lopsided and scraggly, the magic letters INRI.

I checked out *Young Witches & Warlocks* from the library and it is a definite match. To add to your details, "The Wonderful Day" has the 24 hours of wishes affect the people in the town based on a feverish child misunderstanding figures of speech so that, e.g., a woman in town becomes literally two-faced, another has a tongue that wags both ways (with the inside half chiding her for her gossiping), and another man in town prone to wishing gets a horse in his yard every time her utters a wish (c.f. "If wishes were horses"). I read through *100 Great Fantasy Short Short Stories* and it includes "Angelica", but none of the other stories match what you're looking for.

I think that you really are looking for two books, *Young Monsters* and *Young Witches & Warlocks*.

Comment: I was thinking the "popsicle stick cross" was "Stevie and the Dark" by Zenna Henderson, which also is in *Young Witches and Warlocks*, so maybe?

Answer (score 3):

I have *The Anything Box* here, so I checked, and now I am sure that the popsicle stick story is indeed "Stevie and the Dark" by Zenna Henderson.

> He looked down at it--his precious pocket piece--two pieces of popsicle stick tied together so they looked a little bit like an airplane, and on the top, lopsided and scraggly, the magic letters INRI.

He uses the "pocket piece" on a friend/acquaintance and later on a donkey, both of which have been taken over by an evil force.